# Why isn't hexaaquairon ion a hydrate?

Tags: nomenclature

What is the difference between hexaaqua(metal) ions $$\ce{Fe^{3+},Al^{3+}, Cr^{3+}}$$ and a hydrate? Since both of these absorb water into it own molecular structure. Would it be that hydrates have neutral charges where as these have positive charges? Why did we name Hexaaquairon ion it's name rather than Iron(3) Hexahydrate.

Comment: Maybe you meant **hexaaquairon**, not hexaauoiron? Also what do you mean by "absorb water into molecular structure"?

Comment: What andselisk says, and one is an ion, possibly in solution, and the other is a crystalline solid. I.e. hydrates are solids, your stuff would still need a counterion.

Comment: So it's a different name for a different state? But they are really the same thing.

Comment: No. Hexaaquaions are ions, hydrates are, well, hydrates of an ionic (usually ionic) compound.

Comment: So the difference lies in the charge. One of them is when the water molecules attach themselves to the metal ions where as the other it is attached to a molecule of neutral charge instead?

Comment: The point is that hydrates is a term that can be a little confusing. Hydrate can stand in chemistry as a material which contains water, and this can be merely formal, as in the case of carbohydrates.Even ions within their aqueous solvation cage are hydrated. Historically, and at least in my language it can still colloquially happen, many hydroxides were called hydrates. In our case, the confusion can only be made between water- coordinating ions, and salts containing crystallisation water, such as CaSO4 × 2 H2O. Properly hydrates refer to the latter case.